# SP - How to check URL whether ID

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, sharepoint-server, url

How  to check current page URL address for null ID.. How to do this ?

**This is my code, but not correct..**

```
        private int id = -1;

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            try
            {
                if (SPContext.Current.ListItem != null)
                {
                    id = SPContext.Current.ListItem.ID;


                          MyLogic HERE.....
                 }
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it from `QueryString` in farm solution:

```
string id= Request.QueryString["ID"];

if (id != null)
{
//code goes here
}
```

In SandBoxed solution

```
string id= Page.Request.QueryString["ID"];

if (id != null)
{
//code goes here
}
```